# why the "open" command runs under the home directory?

Tags: osx

Under Mac OSX (Mountain Lion), I have a shell script "a":

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal b
```

which run another shell script "b" using Terminal:

```
echo `pwd`
```

Something interesting is that, no matter where my running scripts are located, the `pwd` command in "b" always returns the home directory.

Questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to set the running environment to be the working instead home directory (ie, return the working directory when arriving at `pwd`)

Answer (score 1):

`open -a Terminal b` is like opening `b` in Terminal from Finder. It tells LaunchServices to open `b` in Terminal and it doesn't pass any information about the current environment.

You can use `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` to cd to the directory of the script.

If you want to run the script in a new Terminal window, you can use AppleScript:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd " & quoted form of (system attribute "PWD") & "; ~/bin/b"'`